# Getting invalid pointer address when binding socket in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

On one of our teams desktop, we are getting a strange error when running this code:

```
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(sIPDaddress);
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, m_iPort);
listener.Bind(endpoint);
listener.Blocking = true;
listener.Listen(-1);
```

We are getting the following 10014 error on the bind command:

> WSAEFAULT 10014 Bad address. The system detected an invalid pointer
>   address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error
>   occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the
>   length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an
>   argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the
>   sizeof(sockaddr).

We initially thought it was a network issue but my laptop running the same code works when connected to his network port.

The desktop is ip4 enabled and this is the only machine we are having this issue. We even changed the network card but the error still exists.

Any ideas where to look?

Comment: The IPAddress you're trying to bind to actually exists on the computer?  Try binding to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) with this code and do you still get the same error message?

Comment: What is `sIPDaddress`'s value?

Comment: Do all other computers have the same IP settings? IPv4 enabled and IPv6 disabled?

Comment: Try following from cmd.exe window >IPconfig/all.  The mask or Default gateway may be setup incorrectly.  I usually start by using "PING" trying both Computer Name and IP address to see if you can get a connection.  Try ping from local computer to remove and from remote to local computer to help determine if the IP routing is correct.  You may have a virus checker or firewall blocking the port number.  The computers also need to be in the same GROUP for the connection to complete.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies...I would have expected the network engineers to have checked all this but will relay the responses on Monday as the VPN is currently down. Great!

Comment: Why are you passing -1 for the backlog? That seems like an odd value to choose, and I can easily believe that with at least some winsock providers, it would cause a crash (`Socket` is a thin layer over winsock, and does very little parameter validation, at least in part because different providers have different requirements and limitations)

Answer (score 2):

I found a line above the code above:

```
Socket listener = new Socket(0, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

I switched this to:

```
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

and it worked.

Still not sure why this happened on one the developer machines but not on the others.

What I did notice was when I did ipconfig on a working development machine there is a Link-local IPV6 address shown. However on the non-working machine there is no entry for a Link-local IPV6 address. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: 6 years later and this exact same problem appeared for me after upgrading to Windows 11, using exact same code as you (ie the line `Socket listener = new Socket(0, ...`), I changed to `Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, ...` and hey presto it's working!!